# Including Custom Template on template_include Filter not working

Tags: templates

I have registered a template like this, but on the template, I was wondering how to get all of the current themes functionality to exist on the template, as some parts are missing in the way I have this template set up.

the template file is currently blank, I included wp_head() and get_header() in the template file, it works somewhat, but most of the theme is missing, such as the pages content.

any ideas?

```
<?php
add_filter( 'template_include', 'template_management' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'template_management' ) ) {

function template_management( $template )
{

    return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/the-template.php';



    return $template;
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you copy `page.php` into your custom template, and then modify the code as required. At the very least, your template should look something like:

```
<?php get_header() ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

    <article <?php post_class() ?>>
        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ) ?>

        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content() ?>
        </div>
    </article>


<?php endwhile ?>

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Comment: oh yeagh I didn't even think to do that, works now.

Comment: Or you can just make a copy of index.php an rename it :-)

Comment: @charles then please tick the "solution" check mark below the voting arrow on the left.